# Is there any other solar system in the universe?

Tags: solar-system, biology, exoplanets

1. Is there any other solar system far away from ours in the universe?
2. Why don't we expect another solar system based on another star similar to sun in the universe?
3. If so, Why probably there wouldn't be some life based on those atmospheric conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The universe is made up of one hundred billion galaxies each with between tens of millions of stars to hundreds of trillions of stars. So we have quite a few stars.

It used to be somewhat unknown whether or not stars had planets and if so how many. Recently a satellite called Kepler was designed to look for evidence of planets and found that many stars have planets. Since it is easier to see bigger planets, we haven't seen that many the size of the earth, but that doesn't mean that they don't exist. In fact a few have been detected about the same size of the earth.

The conventional wisdom is becoming solidified that many/most stars have some planets around them, which means that they are "solar systems."

As for habitability, that is the next question that people are working on - determining atmospheric content of planets. This is quite a bit harder of course. As for life or similar life on those planets that is an area of open research known as astrobiology.

Further reading: [Galaxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy), [Kepler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_%28spacecraft%29), [Astrobiology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrobiology).